# r rbind a large list of vectors created unwanted extra columns

Tags: r, rbind, do.call

I am trying to convert a large list of character vectors (2284879 elements and 593.7 Mb) into a data frame. Each list element is a character vector that includes four strings -- these were created from an 4-gram list.

```
class(words_split)
[1] "list"
length(words_split)
[1] 2284879
head(words_split)
[[1]]
[1] "the" "end" "of"  "the"
[[2]]
[1] "the"  "rest" "of"   "the" 
[[3]]
[1] "at"  "the" "end" "of" 
[[4]]
[1] "to"  "be"  "abl" "to" 
[[5]]
[1] "at"   "the"  "same" "time"
[[6]]
[1] "in"    "the"   "middl" "of"
```

The desired result would be:

```
    [,1]  [,2]   [,3]  [,4] 
[1,] "the" "end"  "of"  "the"
[2,] "the" "rest" "of"  "the"
[3,] "at"  "the"  "end" "of" 
[4,] "to"  "be"   "abl" "to"
```

After searching and trying a variety of methods, it seems `do.call` and `rbing` is the solution.

```
words_table<-as.data.table(do.call(rbind,words_split))
```

But the result has 12 columns, instead of 4:

```
    [,1]  [,2]   [,3]    [,4]   [,5]  [,6]   [,7]    [,8]   [,9]  [,10]  [,11]   [,12] 
[1,] "the" "end"  "of"    "the"  "the" "end"  "of"    "the"  "the" "end"  "of"    "the" 
[2,] "the" "rest" "of"    "the"  "the" "rest" "of"    "the"  "the" "rest" "of"    "the" 
[3,] "at"  "the"  "end"   "of"   "at"  "the"  "end"   "of"   "at"  "the"  "end"   "of"  
[4,] "to"  "be"   "abl"   "to"   "to"  "be"   "abl"   "to"   "to"  "be"   "abl"   "to"  
[5,] "at"  "the"  "same"  "time" "at"  "the"  "same"  "time" "at"  "the"  "same"  "time"
[6,] "in"  "the"  "middl" "of"   "in"  "the"  "middl" "of"   "in"  "the"  "middl" "of"
```

If I sample part of `words_split`, say, the first 4 elements, then do the same, the result came out fine:

```
> words_head<-words_split[1:4]
> words_head
[[1]]
[1] "the" "end" "of"  "the"

[[2]]
[1] "the"  "rest" "of"   "the" 

[[3]]
[1] "at"  "the" "end" "of" 

[[4]]
[1] "to"  "be"  "abl" "to" 
> class(words_head[1])
[1] "list"
> class(words_head[[1]])
[1] "character"
> words_head[[1]]
[1] "the" "end" "of"  "the"
> words_head_comb<-do.call(rbind,words_head)
print(head(words_head_comb))
     [,1]  [,2]   [,3]  [,4] 
[1,] "the" "end"  "of"  "the"
[2,] "the" "rest" "of"  "the"
[3,] "at"  "the"  "end" "of" 
[4,] "to"  "be"   "abl" "to"
```

Why would `rbind()` repeatedly combine my lists for two extra times, when the list is large, and when the list is small, it seems working?

Comment: It is likely that one of the vectors in your list has 12 elements and not 4. When rbinding, the lines with only 4 elements are repeated to reach a size of 12. Try `table(lengths(word_split))` to have an idea of the lengths of the vectors in your list.

Comment: Do you get any warnings when you get 12 columns back? Are you sure your list elements have 4 values each?

Comment: Thanks @Lamia, and @AntoniosK. I just checked, and found 124 elements that have length from 5 to 12. I don't know how this happened, because I used the `dfm` function from `quenteda` package to create 4gram, so I assumed all tokens are four words that are connected with dashes. I guess some of the words were originally already including `_`. I used `while` to remove all those irregular elements and then used `rbind`. This time it worked.

Comment: FWIW: `do.call(rbind, words_split)` creates a matrix, not a data.frame as requested by the OP.

Comment: @Uwe, yes thanks for pointing it out -- I actually did have `as.data.table` wrapped around `do.call` in my actual code. My main concern was how to get all the lists combined into a four column searchable data table for further processing. I will edit it now.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in the comments, the result will be correct when all elements have length 4. E.g. ,

```r
words_split <- list(
  c("the", "end", "of", "the"),
  c("the", "rest", "of", "the" ),
  c("at", "the", "end", "of"), 
  c("to", "be", "abl", "to"), 
  c("at", "the", "same", "time"), 
  c("in", "the", "middl", "of"))

do.call(rbind,words_split)
#R       [,1]  [,2]   [,3]    [,4]  
#R [1,] "the" "end"  "of"    "the" 
#R [2,] "the" "rest" "of"    "the" 
#R [3,] "at"  "the"  "end"   "of"  
#R [4,] "to"  "be"   "abl"   "to"  
#R [5,] "at"  "the"  "same"  "time"
#R [6,] "in"  "the"  "middl" "of"
```

However, if one of the elements are longer then four then the following sentance from `help("rbind")` is important

> If all the arguments are vectors, the number of columns (rows) in the result is equal to the length of the longest vector. Values in shorter arguments are recycled to achieve this length (with a `warning` if they are recycled only *fractionally*).

So if add an element of say length 12 then we get

```
words_split[[7]] <- c(
  "some", "char", "sequence", "which", "has", "length", "of", 
  "eights", "which", "is", "too", "long")
do.call(rbind,words_split)
#R      [,1]   [,2]   [,3]       [,4]    [,5]  [,6]     [,7]    [,8]    
#R [1,] "the"  "end"  "of"       "the"   "the" "end"    "of"    "the"   
#R [2,] "the"  "rest" "of"       "the"   "the" "rest"   "of"    "the"   
#R [3,] "at"   "the"  "end"      "of"    "at"  "the"    "end"   "of"    
#R [4,] "to"   "be"   "abl"      "to"    "to"  "be"     "abl"   "to"    
#R [5,] "at"   "the"  "same"     "time"  "at"  "the"    "same"  "time"  
#R [6,] "in"   "the"  "middl"    "of"    "in"  "the"    "middl" "of"    
#R [7,] "some" "char" "sequence" "which" "has" "length" "of"    "eights"
#R      [,9]    [,10]  [,11]   [,12] 
#R [1,] "the"   "end"  "of"    "the" 
#R [2,] "the"   "rest" "of"    "the" 
#R [3,] "at"    "the"  "end"   "of"  
#R [4,] "to"    "be"   "abl"   "to"  
#R [5,] "at"    "the"  "same"  "time"
#R [6,] "in"    "the"  "middl" "of"  
#R [7,] "which" "is"   "too"   "long"
```

without a warning since 12 is multiple of 4.